# Show/hide answers based on specific conditions

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I'm trying to make a multi-question app. Let's take one test for example.
The test consists of 40 questions, and each question has four possible answers.

What's the best way of going about dragging four buttons over a question's four possible answers? How can I make it so when one of the multiple answers for a given question has been selected, the other three possible answers will be hidden?

Then apply the same thing to all the remaining questions.

[image: Like this]

Comment: Do you have knowledge of obj-c? Did you read algorithm books? If both "yes"...you can solve quite easily.

Comment: If you have tried code/logic share them

Comment: i figured a way, but that would require me to code 160 UIButtons, and program each 160 button

Comment: Do you have knowledge about `UITableView`s. If yes, use that and if you don't, go through its [documentations](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/)

Comment: Thank you Zen, i will do so now:)

Comment: Good luck :) BTW,By using `UITableView`s,you wont have to code all the elements manually. Just the common behaviour. Its really one of the most useful class in UI.